# Object allocated without autorelease keyword inside autoreleasepool. What happens?

Tags: automatic-ref-counting

```
 @autoreleasepool {
    MyObject *tempObj = [[MyObject alloc] init]; // no autorelease mentioned here
  }
```

Once the control is out of previous block, does tempObj get released? Even though I have not added autorelease? Why?